# Can't activate Google Play Store and can't cheat gmail account

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

Can somebody help me

I had done factory reset on my phone unite A106 unite 2 micromax and now I am unable to use my Google Play Store can't create gmail account what to do?

Comment: Try reinstallation

Answer (score 0):

You could reboot into your phone's bootloader and re-install GApps (Google apps). You can download GApps from here. http://opengapps.org/

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is wasteing time am asling you google that a cant sign in to my google account google can help me or what can a do

Comment: This answer is non-intelligible.